# Mascara CPF | CNPJ. ao carregar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um script que mascara CPF ou CNPJ, está funcionando perfeitamente. mas ele usa o método  `onKeyPress`, então ele só funciona, quando eu to digitando. quando eu trago um objeto que seja `CNPJ` para mostrar, o campo **CPF/CNPJ**   fica assim: `000.000.000-00000`. quando trás CPF fica normal, com a máscara: `000.000.000-00`

A pergunta, é como eu faço para que o CNPJ, fique com a mascara correta quando eu estou trazendo um objeto?.

Meu script é esse:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Mascara CPF ou CNPJ
        var options = {
            onKeyPress: function (cpf, ev, el, op) {
                var masks = ['000.000.000-000', '00.000.000/0000-00'];
                $('#cnpj_cpf').mask((cpf.length > 14) ? masks[1] : masks[0], op);
            }
        }

        $('#cnpj_cpf').length > 11 ? $('#cnpj_cpf').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', options) : $('#cnpj_cpf').mask('000.000.000-00#', options);
    </script>
```

A mascara que eu quero mostra é assim: `00.000.000/0000-00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verificando a [documentação](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#mask-as-a-function) você verá que o plugin pode receber uma função como argumento. Verificando também o [código no Github](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/blob/d4b031bdcfe367d4372fc13de0dff024e2bef768/src/jquery.mask.js#L391) você verá que os parâmetros passados para a função são:

```
function minha_funcao(input_value, undefined, element, options) {...}
```

E vendo o [código do evento onKeyPress](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/blob/d4b031bdcfe367d4372fc13de0dff024e2bef768/src/jquery.mask.js#L371), verá que os parâmetros passados para o seu *callback* seguem o mesmo padrão:

```
function meu_callback(input_value, event, element, options) {...}
```

Dito isso, uma boa solução para seu problema é criar uma função que retorne a máscara adequada dependendo do argumento `input_value` e usá-la na criação da máscara e também  na recriação da máscara no *callback* do `onKeyPress`.

Exemplo funcionando:

```js
/**
 * Retorna a máscara correta dependendo da quantidade de números na string
 */
function get_mask(input_value, event, element, options) {
    // Remove caracteres não numéricos
    var numbers = input_value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    return numbers.length <= 11 ? '000.000.000-000' : '00.000.000/0000-00';
}

// Usa a função `get_mask` para definir a máscara
$('#cnpj_cpf').mask(get_mask, {
    onKeyPress: function (input_value, event, element, options) {
        element.mask(get_mask, options);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input id="cnpj_cpf" value="11222333000199"/>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

$('#cnpj_cpf').length vai retornar sempre 1 , pois é a quantidade de elementos com id cnpj_cpf no DOM, e sua mascara pra cpf não vai pegar

acredito que o que você queria fazer era:

```
$('#cnpj_cpf').val().length > 11 ? $('#cnpj_cpf').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', options) : $('#cnpj_cpf').mask('000.000.000-00#', options);
```